# Date comparison in Android application

Tags: android, android-date

I have 2 dates in string format like `DD/MM/YYYY`. Now I have to write the condition if `date1` is before `date2`. How can I do this? Please help me.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
Date date1 = curFormater.parse(date1Str); 
Date date2 = curFormater.parse(date2Str); 
if (date1.before(date2)) 
{
}
```

Comment: It gives me error...The operator < is undefined for the argument type(s) java.util.Date, java.util.Date...Did it work for you?